# Importing only a specific class from a Python module with `importlib`

Tags: python, python-import, metaclass

**How would one go about importing *only* a specific class from a Python module using its path?**

I need to import a specific class from a Python file using the file path. I have no control over the file and its completely outside of my package.

file.py:

```
class Wanted(metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...

class Unwanted(metaclass=MyMeta):
    ...
```

The metaclass implementation is not relevant here. However, I will point out that it's part of my package and I have full control over it.

Import example:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name='Wanted', location="path_to_module/mudule.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

This works, and `Wanted` is imported. The problem is that `Unwanted` is also imported. In fact, as long as there is *any* string value given for `name` (including an empty string), both `Wanted` and `Unwanted` are imported from the module.

This has the same effect as in the example before, where both `Wanted` and `Unwanted` are imported:

```
importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name='random string', location="path_to_module/mudule.py")
```

I'm not looking for a specific solution using `importlib`; any reasonable way will do. I will point out that I don't have a need of using the class when it's imported, I only need the import to happen and my metaclass will take care of the rest.

Comment: Any form of import will execute the entire file.  If you can't live with that, then the two classes *shouldn't be in the same file*.

Comment: @john-hen Its a bit out of context, but the Metaclass registers both of them but in a case where the configurations specify only 1 needed "component" if the module containing the component happens to have another derived class both components will be executed and that a problem. But I have my answer, it should be possible to solve it in the Metaclass, I was just hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, the *name* parameter is just used to name the module you are importing. But, more importantly, when you are importing any module, you are executing the whole file, which means that in your case both of these classes will be created. It would not matter whether you wrote `from file import Wanted`, `import file` or used any other form of the import statement.

> A Python program is constructed from code blocks. A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program

Comment: Thank for the input, I kinda suspected that was the case. Any chance there is a way to get the desired behaviour in some other way?

Comment: As @jasonharper said, if it is not okay when both of these classes are created, they should be in separate modules, or maybe you should change the implementation of your metaclass in some way. I don't know the details, so I can't really help with that.

Answer (score -1):

since you named your file "file.py":

```
from file import Wanted
```

If your file is in a folder, you can use:

```
from folder.file import Wanted
```

Comment: I do thank you for the attempted help. But your aproach will not work, as I mentioned in the question "I have no control over the file and its completely outside of my package". In order to simply import like you suggest the file must be part of the packege you are importing from and that is not the case, moreover relative imports are considered bad practice since they are relative to the run path and not neseseraly the file where they are imported.